# Cannot get Postgres.app connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using Mountain Lion and want to switch my rails app from SQLIte to Postgres so I can deploy on Heroku. I have installed Postgres.app and it's working fine if I open it with the path suggested:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql ; exit;
```

But whenever I run

```
which psql
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/psql
```

which is the one that comes bundled with Mountain Lion and is not what I want. From reading around it is a Path issue but the documentation says to add:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

to .bashrc, which I have done. That file looks like this:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run `source ~/.bashrc` in the Terminal window to use the new settings? Or close/open?

You can check your current $PATH using `echo $PATH` as well, and see if the Postgres.app directory that you added is there.

---

Update with the eventual solution: add the line to the `~/.bash_profile` file, as that's the one that Mountain Lion automatically sources.

Comment: Okay that fixed it. I didn't realise you needed to run that command to use the news settings. I was just opening/closing the terminal.

I can't accept your answer yet but I will in a few minutes.

Comment: That should work as well... you may want to move that line to your `.bash_profile` file instead if you've got one because that might be what you're loading up on the login instead of the `.bashrc` file. You can check this by just opening a new Terminal window or tab and running `which psql`; if it's reverted back to the wrong one your `.bash_profile` file is the one being loaded up.

Comment: Oh I see now. Yes, now I've added it to the .bash_profile it works straight away (without the need for the "source ~/.bashrc". Thanks.